# aoe disk as /dev/sda in /proc/partitions

Tags: linux

Im using AoE disk for a particular Linux installation.

I need to tell to linux system to see /dev/etherd/e0.0 as a /dev/sda,
im already create a hard link of /dev/etherd/e0.0 to /dev/sda an it works.

But now i need to make system see the /dev/sda (/dev/etherd/e0.0) in /proc/partitions.

There exists a command to do that ?

thank you.

Comment: AoE refers to : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATA_over_Ethernet ?

Comment: What is your exact requirement? There may be more than one way to do.

Comment: I need to fool Linux OS saying the / dev/etherd/e0.0 is / dev / sda

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that. The `/dev/sda` node is reserved for devices which are accessible using the SCSI/SATA/IDE disk driver; AoE devices do not use that mechanism, so they will always show up differently. Creating a hard link will just confuse matters; doing so is inadvisable.

I'm not 100% certain whether it's even possible to boot a machine over AoE. It might be possible to do directly if all the configuration is automatic, or can be performed by setting kernel command line parameters; chances are that you will need to create a custom initrd to initialize the network and bring up the volume.

Comment: duskwuff, i build the new initrd and boot a linux distro with e0.0 with sucess telling the /dev/sda just creating a ln ( hard link)... But now other install system from another linux verify the /proc/partitions table looking for a /dev/sd devices...  I need to fool the table ... Only hard link not working...  BTW thank you !

Comment: AoE devices do not use the SCSI disk driver. They cannot be made to show up as `/dev/sda`.